# Problems trying to use the Kohana pagination module

Tags: php, pagination, kohana

I have downloaded the [Kohana Pagination module](https://github.com/kohana/pagination) from Git and have been having some issues trying to use it.

I moved it into the modules folder and have updated my bootstrap to include the module...
'pagination' => MODPATH.'kohana-pagination',

I have the following code that loads some messages from a simple table with pagination...

```
public function action_index()
{
$content = View::factory('welcome')
  ->bind('messages', $messages)
  ->bind('pager_links', $pager_links);

$message = new Model_Message;
$message_count = $message->count_all();

$pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
  'total_items' => $message_count,
  'items_per_page' => 3,
));

$pager_links = $pagination->render();
$messages = $message->get_all($pagination->items_per_page, $pagination->offset);

$this->template->content = $content;
}
```

When I run load this in my browser, I get the following error message...

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: 1Call to undefined method Kohana::config()
MODPATH\kohana-pagination\classes\kohana\pagination.php [ 87 ]
82   * @return  array   config settings
83   */
84  public function config_group($group = 'default')
85  {
86      // Load the pagination config file
87      $config_file = Kohana::config('pagination');
88 
89      // Initialize the $config array
90      $config['group'] = (string) $group;
91 
92      // Recursively load requested config groups
{PHP internal call} » Kohana_Core::shutdown_handler()
```

If I remove the code relating to the pagination, the page loads the data fine from the database.  Any pointers here would be great.

---

### Update

Found this link: https://github.com/kloopko/kohana-pagination, on the back of Ikke, so cheers for the help folks.

Appears that the previously bundled pagination module has been removed, found the kohana-pagination module which has been updated to cater for 3.2.

Hope that helps someone else just starting out.  :)

Comment: Just looking at the error, do you have your pagination config set up?

Comment: Which version of Kohana do you use? The config system has changed in version 3.2. And the pagination module isn't officially supported anymore, so I'm not sure if it's already updated.

Comment: @Ikke, I'm using the 3.2, just downloaded and started delving into it a few nights ago.  :)

Comment: @ Brendan, yes, although I'm using the one that came with the package...

`
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
return array(
 // Application defaults
 'default' => array(
  'current_page'   => array('source' => 'query_string', 'key' => 'page'), // source: "query_string" or "route"
  'total_items'    => 0,
  'items_per_page' => 10,
  'view'           => 'pagination/basic',
  'auto_hide'      => TRUE,
 ),

);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is just the config system has changed for version 3.2. Most modules can be fixed by simply updating

```
$config_file = Kohana::config('pagination');
```

to

```
$config_file = Kohana::$config->load('pagination');
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me update you the steps to resolve with Kohana paging.

Go to modules/pagination/classes/kohana/pagination.php

Change the

```
$config_file = Kohana::config('pagination');
```

to

```
$config_file = Kohana::$config->load('pagination');
```

in the same page at the line 199
change this line to

```
return URL::site(Request::current()->uri).URL::query(array($this->config['current_page']['key'] => $page));
```

to

```
return URL::site(Request::current()->uri()).URL::query(array($this->config['current_page']['key'] => $page));
```

Add uri braces.

This resolved my issue. thank you.